# Firebase getAuth() throws error getProvider of undefined but can access database

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I have the following code running on a Node server.

```
import admin from 'firebase-admin';
import {getAuth} from 'firebase/auth';
class MyFirebase {

   constructor() {
     console.log("MyFirebase Constructor");
     this.firebaseApp = admin.initializeApp({
          credential: admin.credential.cert("PATH_TO_CERT/cert.json"),
          databaseURL: "https://DATABASE_URL",
      });
      
      console.log("App name="+firebaseApp.name);

      this.defaultAuth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
      this.database = this.firebaseApp.database();
      // database ref code here...
   }
}
```

and it throws the following error:

> return app.container.getProvider(name);
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getProvider' of undefined

If I remove "firebaseApp" from the getAuth(..) call I get this error:

> No Firebase app '[DEFAULT'] has been created - call Firebase
> App.initializeApp() (app/no-app)

However the "console.log("App Name...")" line produces:

> App name=[DEFAULT]

So clearly a DEFAULT app has been created. Additionally if I remove the "getAuth..." call the database calls pulling data from the realtime database below it work just fine, which seem to imply the authentication worked properly because I can access data from the database.

What the heck is going on?

Answer (score 14):

The new modular apis have a slightly different syntax. The following should still work if you wrap it in a class, but as long as you only do this once at the top of your express? server you shouldn't need to use a class.

Also, I'm using the require syntax but imports should work too depending on your setup.

```
//Import each function from the correct module.
const { initializeApp, applicationDefault } = require("firebase-admin/app");
const { getAuth } = require("firebase-admin/auth");
const { getDatabase } = require("firebase-admin/database");

const app = initializeApp({
      credential: applicationDefault(), //Don't forget to export your configuration json https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup
      databaseURL: "https://DATABASE_URL",
  });

const auth = getAuth(app)
const database = getDatabase(app)
```

It's not super well documented but you can find hints in the Admin SDK reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.auth

One tip: In VSCode you should see the a description of each function when you hover over them, if you have the import path formatted correctly.

Comment: Proper answer. No one mentioned `firebase-admin/auth` - good job

Comment: To be honest, his mistake is correct. Firebase docs are crap on this. Does not say where this comes from and starts using it. The auto import from browser uses the front end import. Just lame. Thanks for your answer, very helpful.

Answer (score 11):

You are confusing Firebase ***Admin*** SDK (Node.js) with Firebase Javascript SDK. The former is for the back-end, while the latter is for the front-end. I understand your confusion because the front-end package/s are installable via NPM, although they are meant to be bundled with front-end code.

You can't do this:

```
import admin from 'firebase-admin' // back-end code
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth' // front-end code !!!

const adminApp = admin.initializeApp(...)
getAuth(adminApp) // TypeScript actually catches this error
/*
Argument of type 'App' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FirebaseApp'.
  Property 'automaticDataCollectionEnabled' is missing in type 'App' but required in type 'FirebaseApp'.ts(2345)
app-public.d.ts(92, 5): 'automaticDataCollectionEnabled' is declared here.
const adminApp: admin.app.App
*/
```

If you are on the back-end, just use `adminApp.auth()` to get the Auth instance. If on the front-end, you need to call `getAuth` with the front-end Firebase App instance:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'

const app = initializeApp(...)
const auth = getAuth(app)
```

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately no, that's not the issue as I already tried that. I do understand the front-end/back-end and this is back-end (the admin stuff).  The Firebase DOCUMENTS for the Admin SDK show

Comment: Hi. After trying "myapp.auth()" (which I had previously tried but to no avail but turns out I had to stop/restart the node server as auth values were cached) I find I can get to the admin functions. That being said, this indicates there is something wrong with the Firebase Admin SDK documentation as there is both a section on "firebase-admin/auth" that shows using getAuth() in their examples, as well as "getAuth().createUser(..." examples, which is what I'm trying to do. Arrrrrg.  I love it when the documentation is wrong and you just spin your wheels for hours.  Thanks.

Comment: I hit something similar this and the front/back distinction was the key for me too. I had a related file in my node.js scope calling `import { getDocs } from "firebase/firestore". That seemed to be triggering some sort of default initialization. Switching all my node.js-side code to use the node.js API (different from "Web version 9") got me going again.